# Listing directory files in a listbox and open them

Tags: f#, listbox, directory, file-listing

I have to list all the files located in my project directory (so using a relative path) in a listbox. I also need to open the selected file in the list (click or double click, it's the same). This is my code:

```
let list = new ListBox(Height=600, Dock=DockStyle.Right)
let dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\tiles\")
list.Items.Add(dir.GetFiles())
```

when I launch my project I have a "System.IO.FileInfo[]" string in the ListBox. How to fix it? What is the correct path string for the project directory?

And about the opening problem?

P.S: I have to load just *.png file in Bitmaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

done in this way:

```
let dir = new DirectoryInfo(path)
for file in dir.GetFiles() do
  list.Items.Add(file) |> ignore
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems a reasonable question to me.

dir.GetFiles() returns an array of System.IO.FileInfo (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss) try enumerating and using the properties of those things in the list.

List of properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to do with how F# handles `params` args, it si slightly different to C# - this will fix the problem

```
let files = dir.GetFiles()
files |> Array.iter (fun t -> list.Items.Add t |> ignore)
```